# Routing in Web API is not working in my integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here's my solution structure:

- **Project A (Class Library)**: Main Functionality API Controllers
- **Project B (Class Library)**: Additional Functionality API Controllers
- **Project C (ASP.NET Web)**: Web API Host (just contains Global.asax and configuration code)
- **Project D (MS Test)**: Web API Integration tests

In my **Project D** I have test cases for all controllers in **Project A** and they all run fine. However, for the integration test case that I wrote for a controller in **Project B** I keep getting the error 404: `No type was found that matches the controller named 'notifications'.`

**What I tried:**

- I initially had attribute routing and thought there might have been a problem, with attribute routing, and removed the attributes and changed my URL to match the default route, and I still have the same problem.
- I thought the assembly wasn't being loaded as there are no direct usage, and hence I forced the type to be loaded using a call to typeof(NotificationsController) and ran an assertion on the return value.
- I tested this with a regular browser and I am able to get the result for attribute routing as well.
- I checked `NotificationsController` is in fact deriving from `ApiController` (through another base class of course, but that is the same base class for all my API controllers)

My test code initialization is like below:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

WebApp.Start(config);

HttpServer = new HttpServer(config);
```

My `Global.asax` code in **Project C** is like below:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApp.Start);
```

In my `WebApp.Start` method, I do have a call to `config.EnsureInitialized()`. I am not sure if it is of any consequence, but I am using Unity DI and have ensured that Unity configuration is also happening in the flow.

What might I be missing at this point? How do I proceed to debug this further. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think, I found the root cause!

My test code initialization is placed in a static method with `[AssemblyInitialize]` attribute on it. I have now removed it and changed it to a singleton pattern and letting the initialization occur on the first use. And I am ensuring my `NotificationsController` type is loaded before this first use. And this solved my problem!

This is loading my controller consistently so far.